# Inserting a character to a substring in an element of a list in python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I want to insert a back slash(\) if an element in a list contains an apostrophe(')

For example if I have a list such as:

```
argList = ['AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'', 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax']
```

I want to be able to transform it to:

```
newArgList = ['AttributeError: \'tuple\' object has no attribute \'rstrip\'', 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax']
```

How would I do this?

So far I have this as code

```
for i in argList:
   if any("\'" in elem for elem in argList):
```

I only want to append an apostrophe if an element has an apostrophe as a substring

Comment: That's not appending a backslash; appending a backslash would be adding a single backslash at the end of the string. Also, you can't actually have a list that looks like that. Can you show us what you get if you `print` the list and the type of the list?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason for you to be doing this, I recommend that you check out the Python tutorial on strings: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the string

```
s = "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'"
```

you can use `replace(old, new)` method:

```
s.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Remember that `\` needs to be [escaped](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) because it's a special character.